Is there way from which we can do real-time speech translation directly and not with speech to text and then text to another language text in flutter
I managed to do the translation with first speech to text and then that text will convert to another language text in Fluttter.
But what i want is to translate the speech directly from one language to another directly.
I managed to do the translation with first speech to text and then that text will convert to another language text in Fluttter.
But what i want is to translate the speech directly from one language to another directly..

Please edit the question to include a code sample and explain how your current code is failing to meet your needs.
